# Send/Receive SMS in Android apps (as default SMS app)

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

As of Android 4.3, how do we send and receive SMS (and less importantly, MMS) messages?

I know there are samples all over this site and the web. But I am wanting documentation for it, and everywhere I look on the Android site says "Deprecated since API Level 4". Is there anything SMS-related that *isn't* deprecated?

SMSManager is deprecated and so is SMSMessage and others.

Answer (score 1):

From android documentation of [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

> Manages SMS operations such as sending data, text, and pdu SMS messages. Get this object by calling the static method getDefault().
>
> For information about how to behave as the default SMS app on Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, see Telephony.

You should see [Telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html) for version 4.4

Comment: Thanks @user3, I did see that already, but on that page it's also telling me that SmsManager is _deprecated_, meaning that we won't be able/can't use it soon. So are we supposed to use something else soon?

Comment: Where i don't see anywhere it says deprecated? Can you point me to there, Where it says deprecated? And if some `api` is deprecated there will be an alternative for that. And AFAIK they documents it. Am i missing something?

Comment: While I was about to send you the link, I have noticed that the page has changed. It no longer says it is deprecated.